# Error handling in an Express route

Tags: error-handling, express, routes

I have a Node module that wraps a RESTful API. This client follows the standard Node callback pattern:

```
module.exports = { 
    GetCustomer = function(id, callback) { ...} 
}
```

I am calling this client from various Express routes like so:

```
app.get('/customer/:customerId', function(req,res) {
 MyClient.GetCustomer(customerId, function(err,data) {
   if(err === "ConnectionError") {
     res.send(503);
    }
   if(err === "Unauthorized") {
     res.send(401);
    }
    else {
     res.json(200, data);
    }
  };
};
```

The issue is that I think it's not DRY to check for "ConnectionError" every time I call this client. I don't believe I can call `res.next(err)` because that will get sent back as a 500 error.

Is there a Node or Javascript pattern I am missing here? In C# or Java, I would throw the appropriate exception in MyClient.

Comment: What if you register an custom error handler middleware?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want to create error handling middleware. Here's an example from Express: https://github.com/visionmedia/express/blob/master/examples/error-pages/index.js

Here's what I use:

```
module.exports = function(app) {

  app.use(function(req, res) {
  // curl https://localhost:4000/notfound -vk
  // curl https://localhost:4000/notfound -vkH "Accept: application/json"
    res.status(404);

    if (req.accepts('html')) {
      res.render('error/404', { title:'404: Page not found', error: '404: Page not found', url: req.url });
      return;
    }

    if (req.accepts('json')) {
      res.send({ title: '404: Page not found', error: '404: Page not found', url: req.url });
    }
  });

  app.use( function(err, req, res, next) {
    // curl https://localhost:4000/error/403 -vk
    // curl https://localhost:4000/error/403 -vkH "Accept: application/json"
    var statusCode = err.status || 500;
    var statusText = '';
    var errorDetail = (process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production') ? 'Sorry about this error' : err.stack;

    switch (statusCode) {
    case 400:
      statusText = 'Bad Request';
      break;
    case 401:
      statusText = 'Unauthorized';
      break;
    case 403:
      statusText = 'Forbidden';
      break;
    case 500:
      statusText = 'Internal Server Error';
      break;
    }

    res.status(statusCode);

    if (process.env.NODE_ENV !== 'production' && process.env.NODE_ENV !== 'test') {
      console.log(errorDetail);
    }

    if (req.accepts('html')) {
      res.render('error/500', { title: statusCode + ': ' + statusText, error: errorDetail, url: req.url });
      return;
    }

    if (req.accepts('json')) {
      res.send({ title: statusCode + ': ' + statusText, error: errorDetail, url: req.url });
    }
  });
};
```