# Express handling CSRF error: can I redirect to a custom error page?

Tags: node.js, express, csrf, node.js-connect

How can I implement a custom error handler in Express using CSRF middleware after users click the **back** button in the browser and resubmit the form? By default Express return a 403 page with lots of stack traces. I want to replace it by for example redirecting user to a custom error page. How can I do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here are some examples of writing custom error handlers in Express: https://github.com/visionmedia/express/blob/master/examples/error-pages/index.js

Here are the custom error handlers I use: [Error handling in an Express route](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19440869/error-handling-in-an-express-route/19450548#19450548)

You might also want to consider modifying connect to return a different code than 403 when CSRF fails. You can change it here: https://github.com/senchalabs/connect/blob/master/lib/middleware/csrf.js#L82

You might choose 428 Precondition Required. The full list is here: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_HTTP_status_codes

That way, you could have a special message shown only for CSRF failures.

Answer (score 0):

Like any other well designed middleware csurf [passes the error to next](https://github.com/expressjs/csurf/blob/master/index.js#L71). So it's possible to react on the raised error in the following way:

```
var csurf = require('csurf')();
app.use(function (req, res, next) {
    csurf(req, res, function (err) {
        if (err) {
            // do what ever with err
        } else {
            next();
        }
    });
});
```